# Do we always start database normalization from 0-NF?

Tags: database, entity-relationship, database-normalization

When drawing an EER diagram, what is the standard order of normalizing? Do we always draw an EER in 0-NF state and normalize it to 1-NF, 2-NF and 3-NF or is it okay to just draw the 3-NF normalized EER diagram at once?

Comment: Normally, you start from 1NF — something that is just about recognizable as a table, albeit with numerous deficiencies, which you remove by normalizing to 2NF, 3NF, BCNF (4NF, 5NF).  As you get more experienced, you start with a design that's close to BCNF anyway and validate that what you've got is in fact in BCNF.

Comment: It is not part of normalization to go through a series of NFs to get to the one you want. Forcing yourself to find a lower-NF version of your design can eliminate good higher-NF versions from then turning up as you seek higher-NF versions. There are algorithms to go directly to 3NF/EKNF or BCNF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalization is refactoring for data. It unpacks complex relations into simple ground facts while maintaining the information content of the data. The goal is to have simple relations that are consistent and free of the risks of data anomalies, so if you can design normalized structures from the start, great!

In fact, there's a whole modeling discipline and diagramming notation built on the concept of designing fully normalized (i.e. 6NF) relations from the start - [object-role modeling](http://orm.net).

The entity-relationship model, as described by Chen, produces relations that are already in 3NF. These can be further normalized when doing logical modeling.

If you're using something like MySQL Workbench or Visual Paradigm, you're designing a physical model (of tables and foreign key constraints) which can be in any mix of normal forms. In this case it would be a good idea to go through the process of normalization even if you were careful to keep functional dependencies in mind while designing. It's really easy to miss things!